# insert date into SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql, ado.net

I'm trying to insert a date into a SQL table, but it when the program runs it gives the following error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
string dateReleased = DateReleasedDate.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");

string myQuery = "INSERT INTO GameTbl (gameName, genreID, players, online, dateReleased, dateAdded, developerID, publisherID, consoleID) VALUES('" 
                + GameNameTxt.Text + "', '" + GenreCombo.SelectedValue + "', '" + PlayersNUD.Value + "', '" + OnlineCombo.SelectedText + "', '"
                + dateReleased  + "', 'GETDATE()', '" + DeveloperCombo.SelectedValue + "', '" 
                + PublisherCombo.SelectedValue + "','" + ConsoleCombo.SelectedValue + "')";
```

Comment: Please use `SqlParameter` s to avoid sql injection vulnerabilities in your application.

Comment: @Klaus: +1 http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use parametrized queries. My eyes hurt when I see string concatenations used to construct SQL queries:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("SOME CONNECTION STRING"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO GameTbl (gameName, genreID, players, online, dateReleased, developerID, publisherID, consoleID) VALUES (@gameName, @genreID, @players, @online, @dateReleased, @developerID, @publisherID, @consoleID)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameName", GameNameTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genreID", GenreCombo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@players", PlayersNUD.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@online", OnlineCombo.SelectedText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateReleased", DateReleasedDate.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@developerID", DeveloperCombo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisherID", PublisherCombo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consoleID", ConsoleCombo.SelectedValue);
    var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ...
}
```

As far as the `dateAdded` column is concerned I would simply remove it from the INSERT and add it a default value directly in the SQL database.

Notice how you are directly passing `DateTime` instances and you leave ADO.NET handle the formats. As a bonus your code is safe against SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateReleasedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: perhaps would be better if parameterised, no?

Comment: @gbn: Sure. Absolutely. But I just gave the solution to fix the error mentioned in the answer

Comment: @dbomb101: What is the locale of your SQL Server and what is the type of the field you're inserting the data?

Comment: Britain and the data is being inserted into a date field type

Comment: @dbomb101: Try `ToString("yyyyMMdd");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put GETDATE() into single-quotes. It is trying to convert the string 'GETDATE()' into a date.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass a date into SQL from .net, IMO, is to use the .ToOADate function.

The function passes in a numerical representation of the date that will work on any database datetime \ date field regardless of the regional setup.

Some info for you:  [ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)